# Switch App Function Service Bus trigger to ReceiveAndDelete mode instead of PeekLock

Tags: azure, .net-core, servicebus

I have a .net core background agent (hosted services)

It handles azure service bus messages with web jobs trigger functions

```
public async Task ProcessSyncResponseMessage(
            [ServiceBusTrigger(ServiceBusTriggers.SyncResponses, ServiceBusTriggers.SubscriptionName)] Message message)
        {
            // some actions
        }
```

As I can see it works in ***PeekLock mode***, but I would like to switch to ***ReceiveAndDelete mode***, thus delete a message from the service bus as soon I get it.

I wonder if it possible with a .net core web job trigger function or not.

**Q:** If so, can you please provide me some tips, how I can set up it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Azure Function SDK works in [PeekLock mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp) only:

[image]

If deleting the message is really necessary in your scenario, try deleting in the very first line of your Function code: [Delete Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/delete-message)